# PFX signing not supported on .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, pfx, code-signing-certificate

On Ubuntu, I executed "dotnet build" and I received the error message "PFX signing not supported on .NET Core". In Windows, I did not receive any errors.

There is a .pfx file that I have found and I have added sufficient permissions as well as created a public signing using sn command but it does not work.